# Как задать путь установки расширений в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, установка, расширения

Скачал Android Studio, установил в папку на диске d, но, по какой-то причине все расширения, эмуляторы android и т.д. всё равно устанавливаются на c. Как задать путь их установки (чтобы они тоже устанавливались на d)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Закройте Android Studo
2. Переместите папку из `C:\Users\.AndroidStudio` в необходимое место, например `D:\AndroidStudio`
3. Перейдите в папку с установленной Android Studio, там откройте в папку bin
4. Необходимо поправить файл `idea.properties`
5. расскоментируйте переменные и укажите новый путь переменным

   ```
   idea.config.path=D:/AndroidStudio/config
   idea.system.path=D:/AndroidStudio/system
   ```

P.S. чтобы эмуляторы и SDK также устанавливались на D: нужно установить переменную окружения `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` в операционной системе

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96546/discussion-on-answer-by-komdosh-------android-s).